# Why does this usage of super yield this result

Tags: scala

I have the following code snippet:

```scala
trait A {
  def print = {
    println("A")
  }
}

trait B {
  def print = {
    println("B")
  }
}

trait C extends A with B {
  override def print = {
    println("C");
    super.print
  }
}

trait D extends B with A {
  override def print = {
    println("D");
    super.print
  }
}

class E extends D with C {
  override def print = {
    println("E");
    super.print
  }
}
```

Which prints:

- E
- C
- D
- A

The way I understand it is: `E` first inherits from `D` and overrides its `print`. `C` then takes precedence over `D` because it is applied later and somehow the `super` invocation in `C` points to `D`.

After that I'm completely lost. I don't know why `A` is invoked but not `B`.

Is trait inheritance and overriding handled differently to classes?

Comment: Yeah, linearization of traits goes in a weird way and inheritance on its own is already confusing. In practice, I have never seen anyone use the linearization trick of calling `super` to stack up multiple behaviours, especially with multiple inheritance; at least if you only extend one trait at a time, the order is clear. - If this is just for learning, go ahead, but if you plan to use this to solve a real problem I would encourage you do not do that, rather open a new question explaining the meta-problem and link to this as an attempted solution, that way someone may recommend an alternative.

Comment: It is very rarely used to provide some decorator-pattern-like behavior. Instead of doing `new A(new B(new C))` where each of them you do something like `def method(args) = inner.method(this.decorate(args))` you simply use `super.method` and trait linearization. But this is rarely done as you rarely have a use case for decorator in FP world where functions can be chained. I did it only in tests with beforeAll/afterAll where I had to combine several resource allocations and releases without too much boilerplate.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Of course this isn't real code. It's on a preparation exam I'm doing. Honestly don't know why professors insisting on teaching and testing this sort of thing instead of something more useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with this declaration:

```
class E extends D with C
```

This reads as

```
class E extends (D with C)
```

So what is the order of `D` and `C` in the class hierarchy?

The `trait` `C` is applied to `D` so it can modify the behaviour of `D`. It must therefore *inherit from* `D`, so this is read as

```
class E extends C extends D
```

And likewise

```
class C extends B extends A
class D extends A extends B
```

And therefore

```
class E extends C extends B extends A extends D extends A extends B
```

But a class can only appear once in the inheritance chain, and it is the highest (least derived) version that is retained. So this becomes

```
class E extends C extends D extends A extends B
```

This hierarchy matches the output that you see if you call `print` on an instance of `E`.

Comment: You wrote class `{C,D} extends ...` instead of `trait` like in my example. Does this change the behavior?

Comment: No, just a slip of the keyboard :) But this is only pseudo-code because Scala does not allow you to extend multiple times like that.